# Changing the DataItem of a GridView in Code behind -- Possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How do i change the DataItem "AmountCollected" in a GridView to something else in Code Behind. I want to change the DataItem to Balance depending on some condition and i was wondering if it can be done?!! This is using VS 2005 using c# and HTML.

Thanks in Advance!!

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="70" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
     $<asp:Label ID="lblTotalCollected" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AmountCollected") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up an `RowDataBound` event for the `GridView`. That event will run for each item in your datasource, and you can modify each row based on your criteria.

```
public void myGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        return;
    }

    Label myLabel = e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalCollected") as Label;
    MyClass myDataItem = e.Row.DataItem as MyClass;
    if(...)
    {
        myLabel.Text = myDataItem.Balance;
    }
    else
    {
        myLabel.Text = myDataItem.AmountCollected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly is MyClass here?!

Comment: It is whatever you are binding to your `GridView`. Meaning, you are probably calling some code such as `myGridView.DataSource = myList;`, where `myList` is of type `List<MyClass>`. The `DataItem` of the row in the `RowDataBound` event is a single item out of that list. If you're binding to a `DataSet`, then the `DataItem` will be of type `DataRow`